# In Hive, how can I add a column only if that column does not exist?

Tags: hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

I would like to add a new column to a table, but only if that column does not already exist.

This works if the column does not exist:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMNS (mycolumn string);
```

But when I execute it a second time, I get an error.

```
Column 'mycolumn' exists
```

When I try to use the "IF NOT EXISTS" syntax that is supported for CREATE TABLE and ADD PARTITION, I get a syntax error:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD IF NOT EXISTS COLUMNS (mycolumn string);
FAILED: ParseException line 3:42 required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input 'COLUMNS' in add partition statement
```

What I need is something that can execute itempotently so I can run my query whether this column exists or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can partially work it around, by setting the `hive.cli.errors.ignore` flag. In this case hive CLI will force the execution of further queries even when queries on the way fail.

In this example:

```
SET hive.cli.errors.ignore=true;
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMNS (mycolumn string);
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMNS (mycolumn string);
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMNS (mycolumn2 string);
```

hive will execute all queries, even though there'll be an error in the second query.

Comment: SET hive.cli.errors.ignore=true; is this properoty applicable for beeline shell as well ?

Comment: Looks like it should have been added in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-11191 . I'm on an older version, so can't really test if it actually works.

Comment: Is there another way if the flag cannot be set because of `Error: Error while processing statement: Cannot modify hive.cli.errors.ignore at runtime. It is not in list of params that are allowed to be modified at runtime (state=42000,code=1)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Well there is no direct way to do that. I mean through a single query.
There are two other ways:

1.) Using JDBC:

```
1.1) Do describe on the table name.
1.2) You will get a list of columns in result set.
1.3) Check if your columns exists or not by iterating through the result set.
```

2.) Using hive Metastore client:

```
2.1) Create a object of HiveMetastoreClient
2.2) HiveMetastoreClient.getFields(<>db_name, <table_name>).get(index).getName() will give you the column name.
2.3) Check if your column exists of not by comparing the list.
```

Hope it helps...!!!

Comment: So, there is no way to do this in stand-alone HQL?  It requires using some compiled code with conditionals in it?

Comment: Well as far as I know, there is no other way. And not through Hive QL.