# Alter Table Add Column if Not Present | Beeline CLI

Tags: hadoop, hive, beeline

I was looking for way to add column in Hive table via Beeline interface only when its not present.

create table employee(ename string , eid string);

alter table  employee add columns (eid string);

```
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Duplicate column name: eid (state=08S01,code=1)
```

is there any way to ignore error or not try adding a column if already present ?

Thanks
Shashi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Hive, how can I add a column only if that column does not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25293019/in-hive-how-can-i-add-a-column-only-if-that-column-does-not-exist)

Comment: I found that eariler but it does not seems to be working for beeline. Solution mentioned in question might work for hive CLI.